# Java regex matching multiple digit sequences separated with colon

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that must have the given format:

- at least `ddd:dd`
- or `ddd:dd,ddd:dd`
- or `ddd:dd,ddd:dd,ddd:dd`

Seeing the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html),
I use this pattern:

```
"^[\\d{3}:\\d{2}]+[,\\d{3}:\\d{2}]*$"
```

Code:

```
myString.matches("^[\\d{3}:\\d{2}]+[,\\d{3}:\\d{2}]{0,2}$")
```

It does not work, but I see no mistake.

Comment: What is `d`?  Character literal or a placeholder for a digit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to notice about your regex is that it has a critical issue with character class (`[...]`, where we define characters or ranges of symbols we want to match or not want to match) instead of a group (`(...)` where we just use sequences of characters we need to match, or use alternations). [Here you can see what your regex actually matches](https://regex101.com/r/zR2xM0/1):

[image]

I am sure `{3}: a single character in the list {3}: literally` is really something you do not want.

If `d` stands for any digit, you need to use something like

```
String pattern = "\\d{3}:\\d{2}(?:,\\d{3}:\\d{2})*";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher("111:11,222:22,222:22");

while (m.find()) {
       System.out.println(m.group());   
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/OGFvph)

Here is [an example with `matches`](http://ideone.com/oZCiNo):

```
String pattern = "\\d{3}:\\d{2}(?:,\\d{3}:\\d{2})*";
System.out.println("222:22,222:22".matches(pattern));
System.out.println("111:11,222:22,222:22".matches(pattern));
```

Comment: If you think it is what you need just let me know and I will add explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Problems with your regex

1. you are using `\d` which matches a digit
2. You are using `[]` which are used for defining ranges

Try `^(d{3}:d{2})(,d{3}:d{2}){0,2}$`

Answer (score 1):

- `[xyz]` - the `[]` signifies that it matches a single character which can be any of thise listed - so `x` or `y` or `z`.
- `(xyz)` is a group and will match the characters `x` then `y` then `z`.

You want this regular expression:

```
"^(\\d{3}:\\d{2}($|,(?!$)))+$"
```

- `^` matches the start of the string.
- `\\d{3}:\\d{2}` will match your pattern; immediately followed by
- `($|,(?!$))` will match either the end-of-the-string `$` or a comma `,` that is not followed by the end-of-the-string `(?!$)`.
- `(...)+$` around the two previous expressions will match  one-or-more of your pattern (if there is more than one then it must be separated by a comma) and then the end-of-the-string.